# To prove $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent for a given joint pdf $f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{4}(1+xy)$

Tags: calculus, density-function

To prove $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent for a given joint pdf $f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{4}(1+xy)$

$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{4}(1+xy),  & |x|<1,|y|<1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

The given solution starts with trying to prove that

\begin{align}
$P(X^2\leq x \cap Y^2\leq y) & = P(|X|\leq \sqrt{x} \cap |Y|\leq \sqrt{y}) \\
 & = \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(u,v)\,du\,dv \\ 
 & = \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\dfrac{1}{4}\,du\,dv
\end{align}

I did not understand how we got to $f(u,v)=\dfrac{1}{4}$ rather that $\dfrac{1}{4}(1+xy)$

I tried with $X^2=u$ and $Y^2=v$, does not work out.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is rather simple. Just verify by a simple calculation that

$\frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} uv \, du dv = 0$

and you're done.

Edit: here all steps: 
$\int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} f(u,v) \, du dv  =  \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{4} \, du dv +  \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} uv \, du dv =  \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{4} \, du dv + \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}} \left[ \frac{1}{2} uv^2 \right] _{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}} \, du =  \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}}  \frac{1}{4} \, du dv + \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}} 0 \, du = \int\limits_{-\sqrt{x}}^{-\sqrt{x}}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{-\sqrt{y}}  \frac{1}{4} \, du dv$

Comment: I am sorry, I dont get it .. I get $0$ from that double integral .. the first integration will give $v^2$ which will cancel out from the two limits

Comment: i edited my post to provide all steps for you

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I still can't add 2 and 2